# location object expected, location array not in correct format, mongo 3.6 + Phalcon Php

Tags: php, mongodb, phalcon

I am working on a MongoDB collection that handles geolocation information. So,

1. I created a below collection Index.

   ```
   db.places.createIndex( { location: "2dsphere" } )
   ```
2. I inserted and found a record through PHP (using `phalcon`) as below

   ```
   $lng = (float) -73.9667; 
   $lat = (float) 40.78;
   $m = new Store();
   $m->location = [
      "type" => 'Point', 
      "coordinates" => [$lng, $lat]
   ] ;
   print_r($m->location);
   $m->save();
   ... 

   $params = [
      [ 
          "location" => [ 
              '$near' => [ 
                   '$geometry' => [ 
                        "type" => "Point", 
                         "coordinates" => [ $lng, $lat ]
                   ],
                   '$minDistance' => 1,
                   '$maxDistance' => 5000
               ]
          ]
      ]
   ];


   $find = Store::find($params);
   print_r(count($find));
   ```

I am getting a below error message:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'MongoWriteConcernException' 
with message 'localhost:27017: location object expected, location array 
not in correct format' in /var/www/html/muyal/cli/tasks/MedicineTask.php:51
```

I presume that 2dshere format is incorrect, is it?

Answer (score 0):

The error message said that you need to pass location object, but you pass location array instead.

MongoDB documentation on 2dsphere use JSON object

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/2dsphere/

> ```
> db.places.insert(
>    {
>        loc : { type: "Point", coordinates: [ -73.97, 40.77 ] },
>        name: "Central Park",
>        category : "Parks"
>    }
> )
> ```

So I guess the solution is to typecast array into object, something like:

```
$m->location = (object) [
    "type" => 'Point', 
    "coordinates" => [$lng, $lat]
];
```